# Why are the results of echo -n "..." different when my script is started different ways?

Tags: shell

I have

```
$>echo -n "\033[40m  "
```

If I evoke it on command line, vs. save it to a file and evoke the file on command line, the result would be different.

I am using zsh on mac, but expect this to also work with bash. Shouldn't output be exactly the same? If not, why?

Comment: type `tty` and see the results

Comment: Depends on details you aren't giving. Are you putting a shebang on your file, so it starts with `#!/bin/sh`, `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/bin/zsh`, or otherwise? Are you invoking it with `./yourscript` or `zsh yourscript` or `. yourscript` or something else? You'll need to show **exactly** what you're doing, and **exactly** the behavior you're getting, for this question to be answerable.

Comment: BTW -- **zsh is not bash**. If you're running code in zsh, you are by definition not running it in bash, unless you have zsh starting a separate bash interpreter to run that code.

Comment: ...edited the title and tags to remove the bash reference -- it might belong there, but the body text at that time didn't support it.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of `echo -n` is different between shells (and zsh and bash are indeed different shells) because it is, literally, undefined behavior: [The POSIX sh specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html) does not require a shell to behave in any particular way when processing it:

> The following operands shall be supported:
>
> *string* - A string to be written to standard output. If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( `\` ) character, the results are implementation-defined.

When using XSI extensions, `echo` is required to process backslash-escape sequences like `\033` with no further arguments given; without those extensions, it isn't required to process those sequences at all, but is purely implementation-defined behavior (thus dependent on your specific shell).

---

As a well-defined alternative, consider:

```
#!/bin/sh
#      ^^ - because this code doesn't use any shell-specific extensions;
#           use #!/bin/zsh if zsh-only, #!/bin/bash if bash-only, etc.

printf '%b' "\033[40m  "
```

The above will behave identically, whether invoked with `. yourscript`, `./yourscript`, `bash yourscript`, `sh yourscript` or `zsh yourscript`, because it's entirely well-defined by the POSIX specification (and doesn't rely on any of those behaviors for which zsh has chosen to break that specification).

If instead you were using extensions specific to a shell, it would need to be invoked either with `./yourscript` (to honor the first line to select a shell according to its contents), with `. yourscript` from that same shell only, or with `<shellname> yourscript`, again, with the specific shell.

For this reason, the `./yourscript` usage is strongly preferred, as it lets the script itself control its own interpreter.

---

Quoting again from the POSIX `echo` spec, this time from the APPLICATION USAGE section:

> It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.
>
> The `printf` utility can be used portably to emulate any of the traditional behaviors of the `echo` utility as follows (assuming that `IFS` has its standard value or is unset):
>
> The historic System V echo and the requirements on XSI implementations in this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 are equivalent to:
>
> ```
> printf "%b\n" "$*"
> ```
>
> The BSD echo is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> if [ "X$1" = "X-n" ]
> then
>     shift
>     printf "%s" "$*"
> else
>     printf "%s\n" "$*"
> fi
> ```
>
> New applications are encouraged to use `printf` instead of `echo`.